# Unit testing that a method was called in another object's method in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, spying

Most of my unit testing experience is with Java and now I'm turning to Python. I need to test whether a method (from object B) gets called inside another method (in object A).

In Java the test method would have to pass a mock or spy version of B to A's constructor to be used when the B method is invoked. **Do I need to do the same in Python? Or is there a simpler way?** (I raise the possibility of the latter, because it seems, from what little I know, that Python is relatively relaxed about enforcing isolation between different components.)

Below is how I do this the "Java way." There are two Python files under test (for objects A and B) and a test program. Notice that object A's constructor had to be modified to accommodate testing.

### obj_a.py

```
from obj_b import *

class ObjA:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.objb = args[0] # for testing
            return
        self.objb = ObjB()

    def methodCallsB(self, x, y):
        return self.objb.add(x, y)
```

### obj_b.py

```
class ObjB:

    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

### test.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from obj_a import *
from obj_b import *

class TTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("obj_b.ObjB")
    def test_shouldCallBThroughA(self, mockB):
        # configure mock
        mockB.add = Mock(return_value=137)
        obja = ObjA(mockB)

        # invoke test method
        res = obja.methodCallsB(4, 7)
        print("result: " + str(res))

        # assess results
        self.assertEqual(137, res)
        mockB.add.assert_called_once()
        args = mockB.add.call_args[0] # Python 3.7
        print("args: " + str(args))
        self.assertEqual((4, 7), args)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Again, is there a simpler way to test that ObjB::add is called from ObjA?**

Comment: Why are you creating ObjB in __init__ of ObjA?  That is not something you'd normally do in Python (unless there is a very good reason for it). Also, ObjB should not be a class, but just a function.

Comment: I originally created ObjB in `methodCallsB`, but I moved creation to the constructor because I wanted to pass the mocked ObjB through the constructor instead of through `methodCallsB`: need the latter method to be a simple function for its use in the non-test code. 

You object that ObjB should be just a function: you do realize that what I've shown here is from much more complicated real-world code that I've simplified for ease of communication, don't you? The omitted parts to the real version of ObjB would complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: JohnK,  sidenotes: it is not a constructor, but a initializer -the object was already constructed, that is why init has `self`. (the real constructor in Python is `__new__`)
In python, a class is not a placeholder for functions, so it is unusual to have chained things like `self.objb.add()` (and it is slower), especially when the object itself is not used.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for that clarification! One might also wonder why someone would make simple addition even a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the possible problems with the design, mentioned in the comment by @Alex, there is a couple of errors in using the mock.

First, you are mocking the wrong object. As in `object_a` you do `from obj_b import *` (which is bad style by the way - only import the objects you need), you need to patch the object reference imported into `obj_b`, e.g. `obj_a.ObjB` (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)).

Second, you have to mock the method call on the *instance* instead of the *class*, e.g. mock `mockB.return_value.add` instead of `mockB.add`.

Your tests actually only work because you are not testing your real function, only your mock. If you do the patching correctly, there is no need to add that test-specific code in `__init__`.

So, put together, something like this should work:

*obj_a.py*

```py
class ObjA:

    def __init__(self):
        self.objb = ObjB()
...
```

*test.py*

```py
class TTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("obj_a.ObjB")
    def test_shouldCallBThroughA(self, mockB):
        # for convenience, store the mocked method
        mocked_add = mockB.return_value.add
        mocked_add.return_value = 137
        obja = ObjA()

        res = obja.methodCallsB(4, 7)

        self.assertEqual(137, res)
        mocked_add.assert_called_once()
        args = mocked_add.call_args[0]
        self.assertEqual((4, 7), args)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation really clarified the matter for me.